# Substitute symbolic expression by numerical value when arguments are knowed in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation, symbolic-math

I have the following symbolic expression in matlab:

```
1861*cosh(1/2) - 860*sinh(1/2) - 728*x*cosh(1/2) + 1800*x*sinh(1/2) + 744*x^2*cosh(1/2) - 32*x^3*cosh(1/2)
```

And I want to get only the coefficients in this way:

```
1.6504e+03 + 117.0598*x + 838.9537*x^2 - 36.0840*x^3
```

How can I substitute expression sinh(1/2), cosh(1/2)... for his value?

Comment: But those numbers are just approximations though, not their real value. The same way that you can not just replace pi with 3.14. What is the level of precision you want?

Answer (score 2):

The following will give you the coefficients in numerical form of the equation.

```
syms x
eq=1861*cosh(1/2) - 860*sinh(1/2) - 728*x*cosh(1/2) + 1800*x*sinh(1/2) + 744*x^2*cosh(1/2) - 32*x^3*cosh(1/2);

coefficients=double(coeffs(eq));
```

However, if you are using the equation programatically later, I would strongly suggest you don't do this, and you keep the equation as is.

Comment: Hi! Thanks Ander. The problem is that I need the coefficents in numerical values in order to implement it in a FPGA, so symbolics expressions are impossible to implement...

Comment: @DiegoRuiz then this is the way to go indeed. I would still test if your numerical equation fits well the original problem, just in case.